# Gzip encoding http responses with Wildfly

Tags: java, configuration, gzip, wildfly

Do you know if it is possible to encode responses from application run on wildfly 10 to gzip format if request contains Accepted-Encoding : gzip header? I would like the change to be done via Wildfly config only and response to contain some indication in header that the response has gzip encoding (content-encoding : gzip).

I have read that since wildfly 8 such encoding is possible with gzip filter, I have tried to add filter to Wildfly config similar to one described here: https://rumianom.pl/rumianom/entry/gzip_content_encoding_in_wildfly, however, with no success. I tried many pradicates like `equals[%{i,Accepted-Encoding},\"gzip\"]` (I found similar example in undertow unit tests) or `regex[pattern='(?:gzip)(;.*)?', value=%{o,Accept-Encoding}, full-match=false]`. Sadly none of my solutions worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter with pattern `<filter-ref name="gzipFilter" predicate="regex(pattern='(?:gzip)(;.*)?', value=%{i,Accept-Encoding}, full-match=true)"/>` worked. If your pattern has special characters like . you need to escape them. 
Note that I did not find any documentation regarding what "i" and "o" values in value= are. It appears that if "o" is given pattern searches header in output from app (response) and if "i" is given it matches input message (request).

Answer (score 3):

This or a variation thereof should in fact work (using Wfly10 and have been doing so for a long time):

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:1.2">
<buffer-cache name="default"/>
<server name="default-server">
    <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" max-post-size="4194304000" max-parameters="10000"/>
    <https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" security-realm="WebRealm" enabled-cipher-suites="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_SHA256,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_SHA,TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_SHA256,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_SHA256,TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_SHA" enabled-protocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" max-post-size="4194304000" max-parameters="10000" record-request-start-time="true"/>
    <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
        <access-log pattern="%h %{i,X-Forwarded-For} %t %r %s %BByte %Dms &quot;%{i,User-Agent}&quot; %I" prefix="access"/>
        <filter-ref name="gzipFilter" predicate="exists['%{o,Content-Type}'] and regex[pattern='(?:application/javascript|text/css|text/html|text/xml|application/json)(;.*)?', value=%{o,Content-Type}, full-match=true]"/>
        <filter-ref name="X-Content-Type-Options"/>
        <filter-ref name="Vary-header"/>
    </host>
</server>
<servlet-container name="default">
    <jsp-config x-powered-by="false"/>
    <websockets/>
</servlet-container>
<filters>
    <response-header name="Vary-header" header-name="Vary" header-value="Accept-Encoding"/>
    <response-header name="X-Content-Type-Options" header-name="X-Content-Type-Options" header-value="nosniff"/>
    <gzip name="gzipFilter"/>
</filters>
</subsystem>
```

You need to define then reference/configure the filters, in your case, at least the gzipFilter.